# Bash script replacing single quote with single quote and backslash

Tags: mysql, bash, quotes

I have a long string which contains single quotes (') in it. I need to send this to mysql so I am trying to replace "'" with "\'" in the variable during the INSERT statement.

Example:

```
"This is the first single quote ', and this is the second '"
```

should become

```
"This is the first single quote \', and this is the second \'"
```

I've seen several examples with script replace and sed, but cannot figure this one out.
Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928156/replace-a-space-with-a-period-in-bash) answer? can you adapt it?

Comment: unfortunately not, since i need to replace one character (single quote), with two characters (backslash and single quote)

Comment: i think somethink like that must be the solution `bar=${foo//\'/\\\\'}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed "s/'/\\\'/g"`:

```
echo "This is the first single quote ', and this is the second '" | sed "s/'/\\\'/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure BASH string manipulation:

```
s="This is the first single quote ', and this is the second '"
s="${s//\'/\'}"
echo "$s"
This is the first single quote \', and this is the second \'
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj: This works in BASH. [You can see this working demo](http://ideone.com/KPYnxf)

Comment: What is your BASH version? Try this command: `bash -c "s=\"This is the first single quote ', and this is the second '\"; echo \"${s//\'/\'}\" "`