# Replacing ' ' with '\ ' in bash

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I am trying to write a shell scripts that will back up every file in a directory.
In oder to get the files I use

```
FILENAMES="$(find -maxdepth 1 -not -path './.*' -type f)"
```

which returns something containing all the names of the files.

If none of the filenames contain spaces then using

```
tar --exclude='archive.tar.bz2' -cvpjf archive.tar.bz2 $FILENAMES
```

does the job and all is fine.

However if there is a file names "bad filename.txt" the above approach does not work and tar will complain that it cannot find "bad" of "filename.txt".

I tried to fix this by using an inline replacement as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928156/replace-a-space-with-a-period-in-bash#5928254), but that does not work:

```
TOARCHIVE=${FILENAMES// /'\ '}
```

Basically what this does is to replace the spaces in the appropriate position, IF I `echo` it. But `tar` does not seem to see the inserted `'\'`. If try the replacement code with two slashes, such as `'\\'` or `'\\ '` `tar` will see both slashes and again complain.

Another solution to similar problems I saw was to make sure everything is in quotes, but that does not work for me since `TOARCHIVE` contains the names of multiple files.

Comment: You may want to use nul separator https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/nul.html - and pass `-print0` to find.

Answer (score 0):

For characters replacement, i suggest you to use `sed`, like this :

```
sed "s/\ /\\/g" myfile.txt
```

This will replace all the spaces in `myfile.txt` by a `\`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not simply replacing `' '` with `'\ '` if you want to correctly quote paths.

Either:

- Use nul terminators (`-print0` argument to find)
- Quote the paths using `printf`.

While not exactly what your asking for, correct path quoting can be done using `printf '%q'`, eg:

```
FILENAMES="$(
    find -maxdepth 1 -not -path './.*' -type f -print0 |
    xargs -0 printf '%q\n'
)"
```

This is useful because it means other strange characters in file paths wont cause issues later on.

If some tricky person runs `touch "foo\ bar.txt"` for example :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to execute the tar utility from find itself:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -not -path './.*' -type f -exec tar --exclude='archive.tar.bz2' -cvpjf archive.tar.bz2 "{}" +
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FILENAMES="$(find -maxdepth 1 -not -path './.*' -type f -printf  "'"%f"'")"
```

Print each filename surrounded by single quotations.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store a list of file names in a regular parameter. Use an array parameter instead. You don't need `find` either; a simple glob will match the same files.

```
filenames=( * )  # assuming there are no subdirectories in the current directory
```

To exclude directories (and other non-regular files), use a shell loop:

```
filenames=()
for f in *; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && filenames+=("$f")
done
```

Once the array is populated, use it as

```
tar --exclude='archive.tar.bz2' -cvpjf archive.tar.bz2 "${filenames[@]}"
```

---

If you had a more complex call to `find`, I would simply pipe the null-terminated list of found file names directory to `tar` without storing them first (assuming GNU `tar`, anyway):

```
find ... -print0 | tar --null -T - --exclude 'archive.tar.bz2' -cvpjf archive.tar.bz2
```