# Bash new line feed in results

Tags: bash

Trying to create a mysql backup script.

However, I am finding that I am getting line feeds in the results:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home
for i in $(find $PWD -type f -name "wp-config.php" );
do echo "'$i'";
done
```

And the results show:

```
'/home/site1/public_html/folders/wp-config.php'
\'/home/site2/public_html/New'
'Website/wp-config.php'
'/home/site3/public_html/wp-config.php'
'/home/site4/public_html/old'
'website/wp-config.php'
'/home/site5/public_html/wp-config.php'
```

Do a ls from the command-line, we see for the folders in question:

```
New\ website
old\ website
```

and is treating the '\' as newline character.

OK..  Doing some research:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928254/175063

```
${foo/ /.}
```

Updating for what we may want:

```
${i/\ /}
```

The code now becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home
for i in $(find $PWD -type f -name "wp-config.php" |${i/\ /});
do echo "'$i'";
done
```

Ref. https://tomjn.com/2014/03/01/wordpress-bash-magic/

Ultimately, I really want something like this:

```
!/bin/bash
# delete files older than 7 days
## find /home/dummmyacount/backups/ -type f -name '*.7z' -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
# set a date variable
DT=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
cd /home
for i in $(find $PWD -type f -name "wp-config.php" );
WPDBNAME=`cat $i | grep DB_NAME | cut -d \' -f 4`
WPDBUSER=`cat $i | grep DB_USER | cut -d \' -f 4`
WPDBPASS=`cat $i | grep DB_PASSWORD | cut -d \' -f 4`
do echo "$i";
#do echo $File;
#mysqldump...
done
```

Comment: Look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice

Comment: try `while read line ; do ... ; done <(find $PWD -type f -name "wp-config.php")` and replace `$i` with `$line` in the rest of your code. (not a completel solution, but should get you thinking in the right direction). Good luck.

Comment: If you expect `"'$i'"` to be `eval`-safe quoting (and are using it in a way that relies on that assumption elsewhere), you'll be deeply unhappy when you run across a file created with `d=$'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''; mkdir -p "$d" && touch "$d/wp-config.php"`.

Comment: BTW, more efficient to `grep DB_NAME "$i"` and not use `cat`. And see [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and/or [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: ... or even `awk -F\\ '/DB_CONFIG/{print $4}' "${i}"`

Comment: I think you should start here: https://www.shellcheck.net/, fix your script and then come back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
find . -type f -name "wp-config.php" -print0 | while read -rd $'\x00' f
do
    printf '[%s]\n' "$f"
done
```

which uses the NUL character as the delimiter to avoid special chars

Comment: `-d $'\x00'` is a funny way of writing `-d ''`. (And I'd argue a *misleading* one, since it implies to the reader the untrue proposition that bash strings are able to contain literal NULs; you'll note that `[[ '' = $'\x00' ]]` is true, and that both these strings have the same length as measured with `s=$'\x00'; echo "${#s}"`).

Comment: ...and should definitely make it `"$f"` on the `printf`, ofc; otherwise you're throwing out any benefits you might have gained by using NUL delimiters previously.

Comment: I prefer the explicit NUL (\x00) rather then the empty string, even if the meaning in bash is the same, to match find.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy f quoted. Thanks

Comment: I understand the added clarity about *what you're doing*, but the concern re: communicating false propositions to readers (particularly when using that code in an educational context) stands, insofar as the obvious presumption about *why* the code in question works (such being that you're specifying a length-1 string that has a NUL *as its contents*) is wrong.