# Replace space with - in shell variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
read -p "enter some words :" $PASTE

curl -s "example.com/${PASTE} | code continues
```

What I want to do is if user enter two or more words I want to substitute spaces with - in `PASTE` variable.

Example:

```
PASTE=default application
```

New paste:

```
PASTE=default-application
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `PASTE=$(echo $PASTE | tr "\n" " ")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace one character with another in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928156/replace-one-character-with-another-in-bash)

Comment: Consider `-r` option of `read` command, then `-G -I` to `curl` for testing URL before *code continues*!

Answer (score 1):

See below, using the '/' modifier to replace ' ' with '-'. Notice typo fix in 'read' command:

```
    # Notice no '$' for PASTE.
read -p "enter some words :" PASTE
    # Replace ALL ' ' with '-'
PASTE=${PASTE// /-}
curl -s "website.com/${PASTE} | code continues
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **sed** to substitute :

```
echo $SOMEVAR | sed 's/\ /-/g'
```

Comment: between quotes, space don't need to be escaped!

Comment: `sed` is a bit overrkill compared to `tr`. `SOMEVAR="some word"; SOMEVAR="$(printf "$SOMEVAR" | tr '[:space:]' '-')"; echo "$SOMEVAR"`

Comment: @LéaGris using [tag:bash], `tr` is overkill too, [dash-o's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59434545/1765658) solution using `${var// /-}` is more efficient.

Comment: @F.Hauri I guess only because `tr` is an external program that takes long to start. The actual search-and-replace procedure in bash seems to be tremendously slow. See [my comment on the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928156/replace-one-character-with-another-in-bash#comment105055999_5928254).